# Yii2 Custom Filter Rule without Anonymous Function

Tags: yii2

I am attempting to filter a piece of input data but would like to do so without an anonymous function.  The first example below works but the second example returns the error listed.  I don't want the couple dozen lines of validation code sitting directly inside my rules so I would like a way to break it out (as in the second example I am trying to implement.

Example 1 (works but is not what I want to do)

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['roles', 'filter', 'filter' => function ($value) {
            // Do some stuff to remove invalid roles
            return $value;
        }];
}
```

Example 2 (does not work but is what I would like to do)

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['roles', 'filter', 'filter' => 'checkRoles'],
    ];
}

public function checkRoles($value)
{
    // Do some stuff to remove invalid roles
    return $value;
}
```

Error returned for Example 2 above

```
call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
    function 'validateRoles' not found or invalid function name
```

Why does the second example above not work?  Or rather, more importantly, what do I need to change to get the second example to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a valid callback, e.g. :

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['roles', 'filter', 'filter' => [$this, 'checkRoles']],
    ];
}
```

Read more : http://php.net/manual/language.types.callable.php

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you! English link for those interested http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use a structure like this:

```
'filter' => array( $this, 'checkRoles' )
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: what do you mean? This is the same answer as marked as Correct, no? Or you mean it is expected to post full function body?

Comment: You used word "maybe" in your answer. If you are not sure whether your answer is correct or not, then post it as a comment.